# What do you call the customizable boxes like in my.yahoo.com?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, customisation

If you haven't seen my.yahoo.com, see this screenshot[image]

I can customize my page, by adding more boxes, removing or rearranging them (I can rearrange using drag and drop, something like WYSIWYG), or changing how each individual box look. Is there any UI term for these kind of boxes? Is there also a term for a website that is customizable in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term that I've seen used for these is ["widgets"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget) or "gadgets" (as in [Google Gadgets](http://www.google.com/webmasters/gadgets/)). The older ["applets"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applet) might also apply - but that term is laden with Java symbolism and might now be confused with iOS applications.

I don't know of a term other "customisable".

The [BBC site](http://www.bbc.co.uk) has a similar layout manager.

Answer (score 5):

Widgets or Portlets are both often used to describe these.

Comment: +1, but I feel like "portlet" is more of a developer's term. I would avoid using that word on the UI

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo *might* be calling them `Content Boxes`:

[image]

Google calls them Gadgets:

[image]